# Appium is not setting and throwing Null Pointer for IOS

Tags: mobile, automation, appium, appium-ios

[image]

Please suggest with appiumdriver

Comment: Please check Image attached for the logic tried

Comment: Please post your code and errors as text, not as screenshots

Comment: What error are you getting? can you add  appium server log?